# Jenkinsfile with shared library

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy

cant figure out, how to overwrite environment in a stage within pipeline with shared lib.

```
def call(Map config) {

if (config.nodeVersion == null) {
    config.nodeVersion = "11.12"
}

if (config.service == null) {
    throw new Exception('Service name must be set')
    // e.g live-client-roulette or  live-client-baccarat
}

if (config.buildScript == null) {
    config.buildScript = "npm run build"
}

pipeline {
    agent any

    options {
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
        timestamps()
        timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS')
    }

    environment {
        NODE = "${config.nodeVersion}"
        BUILD_SCRIPT = "${config.buildScript}"

    }

    stage ('NPM build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    if (BRANCH_NAME ==~ /(master|release.*)/) {
                        environment {
                            NODE_ENV = 'production'
                        }                            
                    }
                    if (BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
                        environment {
                            BUILD_SCRIPT = 'npm run build -p'
                        }
                    }
                }
                npmBuild()
            }
        }
```

And here is content of the npmbuild() function.

```
def call () {
withDockerContainer(image: "node:${NODE}", toolName: 'latest') {
    sh "${BUILD_SCRIPT}"
   }
}
```

But when branch is master environment dont overwrite $BUILD_SCRIPT env. 
Any ideas how can i overwrite it in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that 'environment' clause should stay below stage, outside 'script'.
can you try ?

```
stage ('NPM build') {
    environment {
        NODE_ENV  = (BRANCH_NAME ==~ /(master|release.*)/) ? 'production' : 'dev'
        BUILD_SCRIPT = (BRANCH_NAME == 'master') ?: 'npm run build -p'
    } 
    steps {
            npmBuild()
        }
    }
```

or inside `script{}` you can use the `export` command instead of `evironment{}`:

```
            script {
                if (BRANCH_NAME ==~ /(master|release.*)/) {
                   sh 'export BUILD_SCRIPT=\'npm run build -p\''                           
                }}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not working by this way, too.

1) In first solution there is syntax error > expecting ":", found "}"
2) In second solution didnt overwrite.

Comment: I edited the first solution-attempt and removed the extra '}'. I will try tonight or tomorrow to build a pipeline to reproduce your case and test it. Q: Do you use shared library or just a jenkins file with all the pipeline ?

Comment: I use shared library. There is syntax error inside environment block. I can see it through groovy console in jenkins pipeline job.

Comment: you are right ! I wanted to give you an alternative to if -then-else and if-then but I forgot the ':' in the second line after '?'. I edited the answer now. It's hard for me to write correct code without an IDE